# Create ADO PAT with Azure AAD application

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, personal-access-token

Here's what I have been trying to do:

1. Created an app under AAD. Added the user_impersonation API permission to it. Created a secret and noted down the App ID
2. Been trying to use this python code to generate a new PAT:

```
import msal
import requests

config = {
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id",
"client_id": "client-app-id",
"scope": [ "client-app-id/.default"], # also tried with "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
"secret": "client-secret",
"endpoint": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/my-org/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
}

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
        client_credential=config["secret"])

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])
print(result['access_token'])

pats=requests.post(config["endpoint"],
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']},
            data={"displayName":"new_token1","scope":"vso.packaging_write",
            "validTo":"2022-12-01T23:46:23.319Z","allOrgs":"false"})
print(pats.json())
```

3. I have also tried this bash script:

```
az login --service-principal -u client-id \
-p client-secret --tenant tenant-id
token=`az account get-access-token |  jq -r '.accessToken'`
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token " -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json"  \
-d '{"displayName":"new_token1","scope":"vso.packaging_write","validTo":"2022-12-01T23:46:23.319Z","allOrgs":"false"}' \
'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/my-org/_apis/tokens/pats?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
```

This doesnt work, get a webpage in response. Please help. Might I be missing permissions or something on the service principal?

We provide a server that spawns user-pods at runtime from our docker images. And within the pods we serve a UI that gives access to the bash terminal. Since our users could be non-technical, we'd like them to have pip.conf/.npmrc files with PATs embedded into the docker image. Is there a way to create PATs in  build pipelines, which are not dependent on any actual user (users can get deleted etc) and then embed them into the docker image?

Comment: What is the actual result you’re getting back?

Comment: I get a webpage in the result : 
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://spsprodcus3.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=vssps.dev.azure.com&amp;reply_to= ...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your description and code.

Yes, your permission settings are correct. But from your code it looks like you are trying to use 'client credentials flow' to authenticate, which is definitely not possible at all.

The Azure DevOps API doesn't support non-interactive service access via service principals.

Take a look at this (documentation makes it very clear):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops

[image]

This document lists all the methods available in the package you use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.clientapplication?view=azure-python

I think it should be this method (anyway, you need to use 'authorization code flow'):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msal/msal.application.clientapplication?view=azure-python#msal-application-clientapplication-acquire-token-by-authorization-code

The way to judge whether it is successful or not is very simple, because you use AAD app to create PAT, so the key is to see if the code running will jump out of the login popup or something (must be interactive, non-interactive is not supported.).

Comment: I was trying to follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=powershell#personal-access-tokens-pats) Could you please help me understand what I missed here ? 

@MattSmall what should I be checking to fix this? Were you able to create a PAT this way?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I think I was mistaken on what you are doing.   Bowman above is correct because the requirement to fetch an access token for ADO is user principal - that will result in a PAT being assigned to the user.  A service principal will not work.

Comment: Bowman Zu, I am trying to avoid using my user PAT in the build pipelines. We provide a server that spawns user-pods at runtime from our docker images. And within the pods we serve a UI that gives access to the bash terminal. Since our users could be on-technical, we'd like them to have pip.conf/.npmrc files with PATs embedded into the docker image. While building docker images, currently we have my PAT embedded into the pip.conf/.npmrc . Is there a way to create PATs in our build pipelines, which are not dependent on any actual user and then embed them into the docker image?

Comment: @Seeker I understand what you want to do, but as far as I know it's not possible.

PAT is 'Personal Access Token', which you need to create by user.

From here you can see how the Microsoft backend database stores the PAT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples

Comment: Seems like it's better that we make users set their Artifacts registry authentication on their own instead of trying to set it up for them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bowman Zhu, just to re-verify.. what does this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=powershell#personal-access-tokens-pats tell us then?

Comment: Bowman Zhu, please help understand this blog post as well https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3700/obtain-azure-devops-personal-access-token-programmatically#comment-15919

Comment: @Seeker Sorry for the delay because I have other things to do before. Both docs are teaching you how to use the interactive way (like I mentioned in the answer.)

Take a look at this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Ftoc.json&bc=% 2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fsecurity%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops

Comment: @Seeker And here is an example using python (using the authentication code flow):

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/PersonalAccessTokenAPIAppSample Hope it helps.:)